# How to know whether or not a RST sent by peer , while read/write on a SocketChannel. (JAVA)

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio

Is there a graceful way to solve this problem, given a `SocketChannel` and a readable event ,to determine whether or not the RST has been sent by the peer.

I use `kill -9` to eixt the client process, and at the last moment, I see the client side sent a RST to the server.

[image]

And the latter, the server side received an "readable event". If read the SocketChannel directly, will got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Although it really told the fact, a RST sent by the client side, but the exception type is `SocketException`, which is too generic.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Sadly no, there isn't.